# why laravel 6 many-to-many relationship does not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Hi I simply want to get permissions of the role, I am trying following

```
$r = Role::find(1);
dd($r->permissions);
```

The above script does not return any permission however you can see there is data in the below tables. I also tried following but no luck

```
$role = Role::with('permissions')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

I have data in the table as you can see

**Table:**`tes_permissions`

[image]

**Table:** `tes_roles`

[image]

**Table:** `tes_permission_role`

[image]

And following are Models

```
class Permission extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tes_permissions'

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

And

```
class Role extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tes_roles';

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'tes_permission_role', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Can someone kindly guide me what can be the issue, I would appreciate.

Comment: try `$this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'tes_permission_role', 'user_id', 'permission_id');`

Comment: Why `user_id`? Straight from the docs `The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship`. Also, the columns are called `role_id` and `permission_id`

Comment: @Fjarlaegur that's correct. I believe he switched the places of role_id and permission_id.

Comment: On topic, what does `dd($r);` give you?

Comment: @Fjarlaegur data from `tes_roles` table

Comment: @DinoNumić well, the third argument is to define the foreign key for the model the relationship is defined on. So, on `App\Permission` that should be `permission_id` then right? Or am i mixing up... Edit: Nevermind, i mixed up!

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the order of properties in the `belongsToMany()`. The third argument is specifying the ID for the model defining the relationship. So change to the following:

```
public function permissions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'tes_permission_role', 'role_id', 'permission_id');
}
```

And on the `Permission` model, also define it to be sure.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'tes_permission_role', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
}
```